# How do make e value programmatically in JavaScript like it would behave if a user submit the form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How do we make e value programmatically in JavaScript like it would behave if a user submitted the form?

For example, if there is a function named handleSubmit that only accepts the value of e like `handleSubmit: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void;` but I want to use this function in a useEffect in React and call this function from useEffect instead of an actual form in HTML, So how would I do that without breaking any rules?

This code doesn't work:

```
  const createFormEvent = (value: string) => {
    const event = new Event('submit', { bubbles: true }) as Event & { target: HTMLFormElement };
    const form = document.createElement('form');
    Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', {
      value: form,
      enumerable: true,
    });
    Object.defineProperty(event, 'currentTarget', {
      value: form,
      enumerable: true,
    });
    Object.defineProperty(form, 'value', {
      value: value,
      enumerable: true,
    });
    return event as unknown as React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your createFormEvent function returns a [Submit Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent), so if you are trying to send that return value to handleSubmit, which receives a React.FormEvent which extends a [SyntheticEvent](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#react-event-object), that's why it wouldn't work. SyntheticEvent is an interface but you can create an object to mimic the SynthenticEvent and then it should work.

```js
class MySyntheticEvent{
  nativeEvent: Event;
  currentTarget: HTMLElement;
  target: HTMLElement;
  bubbles: boolean;
  cancelable: boolean;
  eventPhase: number;
  isTrusted: boolean;
  timeStamp: number;
  type: string;
  defaultPrevented: boolean;
  propagationStopped: boolean;
  preventDefault():void{
    this.nativeEvent.preventDefault();
    this.defaultPrevented = true;
  }
  isDefaultPrevented():boolean{
    return this.defaultPrevented;
  }
  stopPropagation():void{
    this.nativeEvent.stopPropagation();
    this.propagationStopped = true;
  }
  isPropagationStopped():boolean{
    return this.propagationStopped;
  }
  persist():void{}

  constructor(event:Event, form:HTMLFormElement){
    this.nativeEvent = event;
    this.currentTarget = form;
    this.target = form;
    this.bubbles = event.bubbles;
    this.cancelable = event.cancelable;
    this.eventPhase = event.eventPhase;
    this.isTrusted = event.isTrusted;
    this.timeStamp = event.timeStamp;
    this.type = "submit";
    this.defaultPrevented = event.defaultPrevented;
    this.propagationStopped = false;
  }
}


const createFormEvent = (value: string) => {
  const event = new SubmitEvent('submit', { bubbles: true });
  const form = document.createElement('form');
  Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', {
    value: form,
    enumerable: true,
  });
  Object.defineProperty(event, 'currentTarget', {
    value: form,
    enumerable: true,
  });
  Object.defineProperty(form, 'value', {
    value: value,
    enumerable: true,
  });
  const syntheticEvent = new MySyntheticEvent(event, form);
  return syntheticEvent as unknown as React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;
};
```

Ideally though I would remove the logic from the function that receives the FormEvent and put it in a new function which just receives a SubmitEvent. Then have 2 different functions. 1 to handle your manually created events and a 2nd to handle the react created event and then send the nativeEvent to the same function. Something like this:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)=> {
    logicWithForm(event.nativeEvent as unknown as FormEvent);
  }

  const handleUseEffect = (value:string)=>{
    logicWithForm(createFormEvent(value));
  } 

  const logicWithForm = (event:FormEvent)=>{
    //logic
  }
```